# What is the reminder when $1^1+2^2+3^3+\ldots+50^{50}$ is divided by 8

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

I have a sum that goes as follows $$P=1^1+2^2+3^3+\ldots +49^{49}+50^{50}.$$

The question is to find the reminder when $P$ is divided by 8.

Inorder to find this, I seperated $P$ into $P_1$ and $P_2$ where $$P_1=2^2+4^4+\ldots+50^{50},$$
$$P_2=1^1+3^3+\ldots+49^{49}.$$

And I realised that $P_1 \text{ mod } 8 = 4 $ and $ P_2 \text{ mod } 8 = 1$.

But I want to know if there is an easier, straightforward method for finding the answer.

Comment: What is your not so straightforward method?

Comment: Think about the evens and the odds separately. Modulo $8$, powers behave extremely regularly.

Comment: Why not include how you got 5?

Comment: @Gary I split them into even and odd terms and look at the sums separately. It kinda felt like a brute force method and I am looking for a more elegant solution, possibly from number theory.

Comment: Edit and add that into question @MuhammedRoshan

Comment: I liked your approach to the problem, relying on the fact that all even numbers raised to a power greater than $3$ are congruent to $0 \bmod 8$. You left out the key step, how you 'realized' that the sum of the odds was congruent to $1$. Here is my take, based on my background: Any odd square is congruent to $1 \bmod 8$. Thus any odd number raised to an odd power is congruent to itself $\bmod 8$. The sum of odd powers becomes the sum of the first $25$ odd numbers, which is simply $25^2=625$. This gives the sum being congruent to $1 \bmod 8$ directly.

Answer (score 4):

This is still kind of brute force, but it's much more optimized, and it's a solution you can easily generalize to $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^k \pmod{m}$ for higher values of $n$.

By the rules of modular arithmetic, when exponentiating, you can reduce the base modulo 8, and then break the terms into groups of 8. So, instead of writing $1^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 50^{50}$, you can write $(1^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 8^8) + (1^9 + 2^{10} + \cdots + 8^{16}) + \cdots +  (1^{41} + \cdots + 8^{48}) +  1^{49} + 2^{50}$.

Further rearranging, we can write this as
$$ (1^1 + 1^9 + \cdots + 1^{49}) + \cdots + (8^8 + 8^{16} + \cdots + 8^{48}). $$

Now we can analyze this by casework, into 8 cases.

- $1^{n}$ = 1 for all n, so the first subcase sums to 7.
- $2^2 = 4$, and for any $n\geq 3$, $2^n$ is divisible by 8. Hence this second subcase is $4 \pmod{8}$.
- Note that $3^8 = 1 \pmod{8}$. Hence every term is the same mod 8. This contributes $3 \cdot 6 = 18 = 2 \pmod{8}$.
- Writing $4^n$ as $2^{2n}$, we see that all terms are divisible by 8.
- This is the same as the third case; $5^8 = 1 \pmod{8}$. Hence every term is the same mod 8, contributing $5 \cdot 6 = 30 = 6 \pmod{8}$.
- For all $n\geq 3$, $6^n$ is divisible by 8. Hence this case contributes nothing modulo 8.
- $7^8 = 1 \pmod{8}$. Applying the same logic, we have $7\cdot 6=42 = 2 \pmod{8}$.
- This last term contributes nothing because $8 | 8^n$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Adding up all the values, we get $7+4+2+6+2=21 = 5 \pmod{8}$. This is our answer.

Comment: Yeah, or mod exponent of coprimes by $\phi(8)=4$ and get each section of $8$ terms contributes : $$1^1+3^{-1}+5^1+7^{-1}\equiv 0\pmod 8$$ except the $2^2$ term and the final 2 terms...